# Matplotlib save animation with many frames

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm trying to save the animation from matplotlib with:

```
...
an = anim.ArtistAnimation(fig, frames, interval=500, blit=True, repeat_delay=2000)
Writer = anim.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=5, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)
an.save(file_name, writer=writer, fps=5)
```

When I save about 5 - 8 frames it works ok, but when I calculate 100 frames and try to save them the saved animation contains only the last frame. It's length is as it should be... but every frame is the same.
I show the animation with pyplot.show() and there it looks fine.
So I'm wandering what's the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When that happens, did you check what is the content in `frames`? It may not be a problem animation, but from the previous part generating the frames. You may also just clear all the variables and then have a fresh run with 100 frames.

Comment: I did check frames and it's fine... I also show the animation with pyplot and there the animation frames are what they are supposed to be. But when I save the same animation as mp4 or gif and try to open it afterwords then all the frames are the same ( only the last frame ). I tried to save fewer frames and if I save 5 or less frames then the saved animation is also ok...